# Understanding dequeue_rt_stack() for RT scheduling class linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

`enqueue_task_rt` function in `./kernel/sched/rt.c` is responsible for queuing the task to the run queue. `enqueue_task_rt` contains call to `enqueue_rt_entity` which calls `dequeue_rt_stack`. Most part of the code seems logical but I am a bit lost because of the function `dequeue_rt_stack` unable to understand what it does. Can somebody tell what is the logic that I am missing or suggest some good read.

Edit: The following is the code for `dequeue_rt_stack` function

```
     struct sched_rt_entity *back = NULL;
     /* macro for_each_sched_rt_entity defined as
     for(; rt_se; rt_se = rt_se->parent)*/
     for_each_sched_rt_entity(rt_se) {
             rt_se->back = back;
             back = rt_se;
     }

     for (rt_se = back; rt_se; rt_se = rt_se->back) {
             if (on_rt_rq(rt_se))
                     __dequeue_rt_entity(rt_se);
     }
```

More specifically, I do not understand why there is a need for this code:

```
     for_each_sched_rt_entity(rt_se) {
             rt_se->back = back;
             back = rt_se;
     }
```

What is its relevance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a task is to be added to some queue, it must first be removed from the queue that it currently is on, if any.

With the [group scheduler](http://lwn.net/Articles/240474/), a task is always at the lowest level of the tree, and might have multiple ancestors:

```
       NULL
         ^
         |
+-----parent------+
|                 |
| top-level group |
|                 |
+-----------------+
         ^      ^_____________
         |                    \
+-----parent------+   +-----parent------+
|                 |   |                 |
| mid-level group |   |   other group   |  ...
|                 |   |                 |
+-----------------+   +-----------------+
         ^      ^_____________
         |                    \
+-----parent------+   +-----------------+
|                 |   |                 |
|      task       |   |   other task    |  ...
|                 |   |                 |
+-----------------+   +-----------------+
```

To remove the task from the tree, it must be removed from all groups' queues, and this must be done first at the top-level group (otherwise, the scheduler might try to run an already partially-removed task). Therefore, `dequeue_rt_stack` uses the `back` pointers to constructs a list in the opposite direction:

```
   NULL    back
     ^      |
     |      V
+-parent----------+
|                 |
| top-level group |
|                 |
+----------back---+
     ^      |   ^_____________
     |      V                 \
+-parent----------+   +-----parent------+
|                 |   |                 |
| mid-level group |   |   other group   |  ...
|                 |   |                 |
+----------back---+   +-----------------+
     ^      |   ^_____________
     |      V                 \
+-parent----------+   +-----------------+
|                 |   |                 |
|      task       |   |   other task    |  ...
|                 |   |                 |
+----------back---+   +-----------------+
            |
            V
           NULL
```

That `back` list can then be used to walk down the tree to remove the entities in the correct order.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Very succinct and yet so clearly explained. Saved me countless hours of confusion. I wish the Linux kernel scheduler code has more such commentary as inline comments in code.

Answer (score 1):

I am a fresh man in kernel hacking. This is my first time to answer linux kernel question.
Maybe this help to you.

I read the source code. I think it maybe relates to group scheduling.

When kernel have these codes:

```
#ifdef CONFIG_RT_GROUP_SCHED
```

It represents that we can collect some schedule entities in to one schduling group.

```
static void enqueue_rt_entity(struct sched_rt_entity *rt_se, bool head)
```

{

```
    dequeue_rt_stack(rt_se);
    for_each_sched_rt_entity(rt_se)
          __enqueue_rt_entity(rt_se, head);
```

}

Function dequeue_rt_stack(rt_se) extracts all the scheduling entities belong to the group, then add them to run queue.

[Hierarchical group I/O scheduling](http://lwn.net/Articles/427961/)

[CFS group scheduling](http://lwn.net/Articles/240474/)

Comment: I also think the same way but why there is a need to do the same, why first dequeue all and then en-queue again.

Comment: For example, if there is a little group of entities scheduling on the run queue. Then some events happend. A bigger group includes above group need to be scheduled on the run queue. Note that some entities in the bigger group may be not on the run queue.  Remove the little group from rq ,then put the little group with other entities on the run queue at a time. Oh,  I am sorry. I can't express more clearly. Maybe some fault in this explanations. Reading more source code will be good to find the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it was definitely helpful. I will try to figure out more.